Simplifying a quadratic expression under square root
I am trying to simplify the following expression
$$\sqrt{R}:=\sqrt{a^2(u_1-u_2)^2+b^2(u_1+u_2)^2-2 ab (u_1^2+u_2^2-2)}$$
I have been staring at it for a while in the hopes of getting rid of the square root, or find a simpler factorization, but no luck so far.
Introducing the shorthand notation $A=a(u_1-u_2)$ and $B=b(u_1+u_2)$, we have
$$R-4ab=(A-B)^2-4abu_1^2$$
or
$$R-4ab=(A+B)^2-4abu_2^2$$
This means that
$$R-4ab=A^2+B^2-2ab(u_1^2+u_2^2)$$
I also know that $-1<u_1<1$ and $-1<u_2<1$ and $a>0,b>0$. All values are assumed to be real, but perhaps one can simplify the expressions if we relax this condition.
Is it possible to construct a coordinate transformation that turns $R$ to a perfect square?

It doesn't look like the radical expression is algebraically a perfect square. However, it does look an awful lot like the Law of Cosines, so maybe it geometrically represents the square of the length of some helpful segment in a figure. ... What's the context of this expression?

The expressions are related to maximum-likelihood parameters for a certain class of maximum entropy models on binary variables. u1 and u2 are the expectation values for the functions associated to these parameters. Your intuition that this looks like the law of cosines could very well be correct, but perhaps for hyperbolic trig functions, since these always show up in these kinds of problems.
